# Eclipse create java executable with external libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, export, lwjgl

I've seen this topic in this forum but it I need a more basic explanation on how to do this.

I've done a program in Java with some external libraries (LWJGL and Slick).

So this is what I've done and my program won't start anyway, tell me where I've done wrong.

I have Eclipse 3.7.1

1. My project is opened in Eclipse and runs well in Eclipse
2. I click File -> Export
3. I select Java -> Runnable JAR file
4. Here I don't know what to choose in Launch configuration, when I click the dropdown I get the option to choose my main class so I do that.
5. I select an export destination
6. I select the option "Package required libraries into generated JAR" under Library Handling
7. I don't know what ANT script is so I don't use that
8. I click Finish
9. I copy my images-folder to the same location as the generate JAR-file
10. I try to start the JAR-file, something loads in the background but nothing happens, no window shows up, nothing.
11. I check the Task manager in windows and sees that a javaw.exe is running

What did I miss?

My program uses images for graphics like this:

```
image = new Image("images/filname.png");
```

I wonder if I need to change the paths before exporting or the method to load these?

Thanks!

Comment: Check what exception is getting thrown - run the JAR from the command-line: `java -jar filename.jar`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get things from inside a jar file you need to have them in your classpath and access them as resources.

The constructor you use, refers to a physical file which cannot peek inside a jar-file.

---

(EDIT)  Also note that you have no guarantee where the current working directory is.  Hence any relative references may break, as you see.

Comment: How do I add images to a classpath and access them as resources?

Comment: I agree, he should package the images inside the JAR - but it doesn't sound like that's causing the problem in this case... it sounds like he's loading his images as files - he builds the JAR, then copies his images folder to the same location as the JAR file.  This should work.

Answer (score 0):

[Read this](http://thecodinguniverse.com/lwjgl-exporting-as-jar) to learn how to use JarSplice to export your Eclipse project to a runnable jar-file. Regarding images, you can put them in the same directory as a class file (in the jar) and then write

```
SampleClass.class.getResourceAsStream("image.png")
```

to retrieve an InputStream of the image. Then you can load it however you like.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I was able to fix it. All I did was copy the data folder (which contains my resources) *into* the *.jar file. You can do this for example with WinRAR.